# Должна ли быть наклейка при лицензировании windows 7?

Tags: windows, лицензирование

Здравствуйте!

Моя фирма закупила 4 электронных лицензии на windows 7. Из письма менеджера по продажам мне:

*Электронная лицензия - Данный вид лицензии не имеет физической оболочки и поставляется на эл. почту в ввиде ключа состоящего из 5-ти блоков букв и цифр, а также ссылкой для загрузки дистрибутива.*

Один из программистов говорил мне, что обязательно к каждой лицензии должна прилагаться наклейка, которая наклеивается на корпус компьютера. Иначе лицензия - полное фуфло.

**Вопрос:** Электронная "безнаклеечная" лицензия - это миф фирм-барыг или реальность? Обязательна ли на самом деле наклейка на корпусе компа?

Comment: Вы бы лучше спросили это у Microsoft. А то мы вам насоветуем, а штрафы платить вам, а не нам, если что.

Comment: *Обязательна ли на самом деле наклейка на корпусе компа?* Вот уж точно нет... представь себе терминальный сервер на 100 сеансов (и соответственно 100 копий одновременно работающих ОС), обклеенный наклейками...

Comment: @VladD я хотел спросить microsoft. А они мою учётку блокирнули, требуют номер телефона дать. Короче не по понятиям себя ведут.

Comment: Вам для бизнеса? А в чём проблема дать рабочий номер телефона? Если вы играетесь в анонима, понятно, что они не будут вам доверять. Спросите как юридическое лицо, оставьте реквизиты предприятия.

Comment: @VladD вы не переживайте за дурные советы. Мы их тут заминусуем, вместе с другими людьми, которые придут из сети по вопросу, а потом нарвуться на штрафы.

Comment: Это плохая стратегия. Ну вы заминусуете, но штраф-то вы заплатите при этом. Плохо. Или хуже того, у вас случайно обойдётся, неправильный ответ заплюсуют, а потом многие другие люди попадутся. В юридических вопросах лучше обращаться к юристу, а не к «помощи клуба».

Comment: @VladD, я создал 4 января учётку, когда качнул VS 2017. Эти персонажи вон чё учудили - нельзя войти в IDE без учётки. Ну в Apple решили скатиться. Хотел вопрос задать - без учётки нельзя. Ладно. Учётка заблокирована.  Короче в случае сутяжничества, у меня сильные карты, так что могу и болт положить на лицензию.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Хм, как это нельзя войти? Вы скачали Community Edition или что-то, что требует лицензии? Я работаю с Community Edition без лицензии и без учётки, полёт нормальный.

Comment: @VladD, возможно вы работаете в VS 2015 или ниже. Не в 2017. А может быть, я просто создал по ошибке в 2017, полагая что без этого никуда.  Суть не в этом.

Comment: Пока вы будете судиться с майкрософт и проверяющими органами в РФ - ваши сервера и рабочие станции будут пылиться на складах и ваши т.н. "сильные позиции" -- это ущерб для бизнеса, годами без оборудования. У кого ресурсы кончатся годами ждать быстрее - у вас или майкрософт? Готовы ли вы судиться с гос.органами в стране, где 98% приговоров - обвинительные? А ваше "у меня заблокировали учётку, поэтому я обиделся и не стал делать больше попыток связаться с вендором" вы принесите в суд и посмотрите, что с этим сделает судья. Удачи.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin: Я работаю совершенно точно в VS 2017. Я использую C# 7.2, который в младших версиях VS не поддерживается. Ну и на моей VS таки написано 2017. // Теперь по поводу «сильной позиции». По закону, вы обязаны соблюдать лицензию. То, что ваш акк забанили, не даёт вашей фирме права нарушать лицензию. Это не российская специфика, так работает закон везде.

Comment: Я бы очень сильно советовал всё же поговорить с адвокатом. Всё, что мы тут говорим, это болтовня программистов, а вот мнение юриста — серьёзная, веская штука.

Comment: Наклейка обязана быть на диске только при физической покупке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос я [задал](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install-winactivate/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8/7550128f-299a-433a-b2d6-b58dad463a14) в `microsoft`. Майкрософт озверела, поэтому пришлось им дать свой номер телефона чтобы завести аккаунт. Из ответа следовало:

**1.**  Наклейка на корпус компа не является обязательной составляющей лицензионной версии. Эти наклейки клеятся на компьютеры с предустановленной версией `windows`. Все коробочные версии `windows` наклейками не снабжаются.

**2.** Электронная лицензия не миф. Но эту лицензию распространяет только microsoft. Партнёры эту лицензию не распространяют. А менеджер сомнительной фирмы, который прислал ключ, продал только набор символов. И он за последствия использования нелицухи не отвечает. Дополнительный прикол в том, что мелкомягкие могут сбросить не лицензионный ключ при установке обновлений.

Comment: По вашей ссылке: *"За исключением карточек с ключом продукта (PKC), которые распространяются с сертификатами подлинности"*. Сертификат подлинности - это и есть та самая наклейка. Так что не обязательно windows должна быть предустановленной.